# Does adding non-variable quantifiers to a proposition change the proposition?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Let:

$A,B,C$ be non-empty sets.

$P(z)$ is a one variable proposition.

Then are the following propositions equivalent?

$\forall\ z \in C, P(z)$

$\forall\ x \in A, [\forall\ z \in C, P(z)] $

$\exists\ x \in A, [\forall\ z \in C, P(z)] $

$\forall\ x \in A, \forall\ y \in B, [\forall\ z \in C, P(z)] $

$\forall\ x \in A, \exists\ y \in B, [\forall\ z \in C, P(z)] $

$\exists\ x \in A, \forall\ y \in B, [\forall\ z \in C, P(z)] $

$\exists\ x \in A, \exists\ y \in B, [\forall\ z \in C, P(z)] $

If yes, why?

Comment: Adding a leading quantifier that quantifies a variable that is not free in formula $P(z)$ does **not** change the meaning (and truth value) of the formula. In general $\forall x \alpha \equiv \alpha$ is $x$ is not free in $\alpha$ (and the same for $\exists$).

Comment: See [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) and [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation).

Comment: I got my answer from Mauro ALLEGRANZA